# Using Haskell with a database backend for "business applications"

Tags: database, haskell

I would like to know if there is any possibility that I can use Haskell with small database like sql server compact so that client wont have to install any server on his desktop.

Is there any api providing sql statements and so on ...
What is the best solution to achieve small database application using haskell.

thanks for help

Comment: have you seen HDBC? http://wiki.github.com/jgoerzen/hdbc/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a great option for a small, lightweight database you can embed in your application. See [HackageDB](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite) for a Haskell binding.

Answer (score 9):

There are [57 database libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:database) and tools for Haskell on Hackage. The most popular is HDBC, an order of magnitude more popular than anything else, and has the HDBC-sqlite backend.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend SQLite. If you are looking for a library to help keep the type safety of Haskell with a concise syntax, I would recommend checking out [Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent), which has a SQLite backend.